# Node.js "net.createConnection()" error callback not emitting

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I want to connect to a Unix Domain Socket server in a Node application. If the connection succeeds and was opened, a loop (that may take some time) shall be executed. If an error occurs during the execution of this loop, it should receive some kind of notification. If a connection to the client is not possible at all, the loop should not be executed in the first place (that seems to work with the Promise). To me this sounds like the most simple thing in the world, but I just can't get it to work... This is what I have until now:

```
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let connection = net.createConnection('/tmp/socket.s', () => {resolve(connection);})
      .on('data', function(data) {
        // Do something (during loop execution)
      })
      .on('error', reject); // If this callback is executed, the while loop should terminate (by receiving some kind of signal within the loop)
  }).then(function(connection) {
    for(...) {
      // Do stuff that takes some time, executes other callbacks, sends data to the socket
    }
    connection.end();
  }, function(error) {
    // Error handling
  });
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to listen to the data event in the resolve section of the promise. The following code should do it:

```
const net = require('net');

/**
 * Client
 * --------------------------------------------
 */

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let client = net.createConnection({ path: '/tmp/socket.s'}, () => {
        console.log('Client: connected ')
        resolve(client);
    });

    // Reject on error
    client.on('error', err => reject(err) );

    client.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Client: disconnected from server #1');
    });
}).then( connection => {
    connection.on('data', data => {

        // Do stuff with the data
        console.log(`Client: the server says: ${data.toString()}\n`);

        if(data != 'Data recieved'){
            // Just to ensure that the following loop runs only once
            for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    // Send data to the server
                    connection.write(`Client Data ${i}`);
                    if (i == 10) {
                        // Close the connection after everything is done
                        connection.end();
                    }
                }, i*2000);
            }
        }
    });
}, error => {
    console.log('Client: promise rejection error', error );
});
```

My test server looks like this

```
const net = require('net');


/**
 * Server
 * --------------------------------------------
 */

const server = net.createServer( connectionListener => {
    console.log(`#${process.pid} Server: client connected`);
    connectionListener.on('end', () => {
        console.log(`#${process.pid} Server: client disconnected`);
    });
    connectionListener.write('Hello\r\n');
    connectionListener.on('data', data => {
        console.log(`#${process.pid} Server: client sends: ${data.toString()}`);
        connectionListener.write('Data recieved');
    });
});

server.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    server.close();
});
server.listen('/tmp/socket.s', () => {
    console.log(`#${process.pid} Server: server bound`);
});

process.on('exit', code => {
    console.log(code);
    server.close();
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => server.close() );

process.on('SIGINT', () =>  server.close() );
```

In this example the client sends data to server and the server replies each time. The client then closes the connection after having sent data 10 times.

P.S. There is no need to use a Promise unless you do need to return a promise at some point in your code.